# Angular2 how to set element class name when using ng-for, only on first element

Tags: angular

I have building a `ul` and want to set the class only on the first `li` element.

I want to set the `class="active"` only on the first li.  I do get the index into the class attribute but that isn't what I want.

```js
import { Component, View, NgFor,Inject,forwardRef,Input, NgIf,  FORM_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/angular2';
@Component({
    selector: 'tabs'
})
@View({
    template: `
        <ul>
           <li *ng-for="#tab of tabs;#index = index" class="{{index}}" (click)="selectTab(tab)">{{tab.tabTitle}}</li>
        </ul>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
  `,
    directives: [NgFor]
})

export class Tabs {
    get tabs() {
        return this._tabs;
    }

    set tabs(value) {
        this._tabs = value;
    }
    private _tabs;

    constructor() {
        console.log("ctor.Tabs");
        this._tabs = [];
    }

    selectTab(tab) {
        this._tabs.forEach((tab) => {
            tab.active = false;
        });
        tab.active = true;
    }

    addTab(tab: Tab) {
        if (this._tabs.length === 0) {
            tab.active = true;

        }
        else {
            tab.active = false;
        }
        this._tabs.push(tab);
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'tab',
    properties: ['tabTitle: tab-title']
})
@View({
    template: `
    <div [hidden]="!active" [class]="active">
      <ng-content/>
    </div>
  `
})
export class Tab {
    @Input() index: number;

    constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => Tabs)) tabs: Tabs) {
        console.log("ctor.Tab") ;
        tabs.addTab(this);
        console.log(tabs);
    }

    get active() {
        return this._active;
    }
    set active(value) {
        this._active = value;
    }
    private _active;


}
```

Comment: `[class.active]="index == 0"`

Comment: @Eric - Perfect. Thank you. (make it an answer)

Comment: Oh, ok, right away :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As requested by @jeff

You can achieve by simply using this line

```js
<li *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let index = index" [class.active]="index == 0" ...>
```

Glad it helped :)

**Update**

With beta 15 the `first` local variable was added, so the original solution can be rewritten as

```
<li *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let isFirst = first" [class.active]="isFirst" ...>
```

See [Angular 2 - ngFor - local variable “first” does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856897/angular-2-ngfor-local-variable-first-does-not-work/35856997#35856997)

Comment: if I wanna to add `is-active`, how to achieve that? `[class['is-active']]=isFirst` does not work.

Comment: I really did not believe this would work. BUUUT it does... So I guess I need to study angular syntax better... Thanks for the elegant solution :)

Comment: in this code `<li *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let index = index" [class.active]="index == 0" ...>` class.active, is `active` a class you set? or some reserved property? If not, can I do `class.myName` ?

Answer (score 3):

Hash syntax gives me `Template parse errors` (@angular 2.2.0), I had to use `let` instead.

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index; let firstItem = first; let lastItem = last" [ngClass]="{ active: firstItem }">
    {{ i }} {{ firstItem }} {{ lastItem }} {{ item }} 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

As of this post date the docs show:

```
first as isFirst
```

so:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; first as isFirst">
    ... etc
```