# Angular 2 - ngFor - local variable "first" does not work

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am using ngFor loop to create a list with buttons to move objects around.  I have attempted to use the ngFor variables first and last to disable certain buttons.  I am finding "first" does not work

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="#hero of heroes; #i=index, #first=first, #last=last">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" [disabled]="first" (click)="moveToTop(hero, i)">Top</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" [disabled]="first" (click)="moveUp(hero, i)">Up</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" [disabled]="last" (click)="moveDown(hero, i)">Down</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" [disabled]="last" (click)="moveToBottom(hero, i)">Bottom</button>
</li>
```

I have a working example here [Plunker preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zi4fwDjAWepGkuevAXZx?p=preview)

Am I doing this correctly?  I know I could do

```
[disabled]="i==0"
```

but I was thinking "first" and "last" looked more elegant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For now you can use `[disabled]="i === 0"` since the local variable `first` doesn't exist, but there's a [pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/6528) to add it, not yet mergerd though.

**Update**

The pull request reference above it landed with beta.15, you can see the changelog https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md.

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/kElfnVRJQ31o0MDcxLHJ?p=preview) with `first` working. You can see the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html) as well.

Comment: Sorry for the poor answer, not sure how to elaborate it more.