# How do I change Button States in Angular 6?

Tags: css, angular

I am new to Angular 6, my website contains a section which displays a set of buttons formed dynamically as follows

```
<button class="card-button" *ngFor="let env of product.env" name="button">{{env.name}}</button>
```

Also, I want to display different border of a button which is selected by default as

```
button:focus {
      border-bottom: 4px solid #CC292B;
      color: #CC292B;
}
button{
      border-bottom: 4px solid green;
      color: green;
}
```

Now If the button is selected it should come up with `color: #CC292B;` and green otherwise. Through the above CSS, I was able to achieve the task. Now I wanted the first button to be selected by default i.e the first should appear with `color: #CC292B;` and rest with green color, how can I achieve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, you should try to put "autofocus" on your first element during your *ngFor. This could help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33771699/7415107

Comment: *ngFor not only allow let index=i, else let first=first, let last=last, let odd=odd.. see https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ngClass` to achieve that:

```
<button class="card-button" *ngFor="let env of product.env; let i = index" [ngClass]="[i == 0 ? 'button-active' : 'button-standard']" name="button">{{env.name}}</button>
```

and you can have this kind of css

```
.button-active{
color:red;
}

.button-standard{
color: green;
}
```

Comment: very nice! i used this in the following way `<button *ngFor="let value of values" (click)="selectedValue = value" [ngClass]="{selected: selectedValue === value}">{{value}}</span></button>`, along with `selectedValue: string;` in the `component.ts`

Comment: That's also good! The main difference between using  `{ ... }` instead of `[ ... ]` is that you can't catch the `else` statement using the first notation.

Answer (score 1):

Create two `class` for `selected` and `notselected`. Apply class `selected` if it is first button, otherwise `notselected`

```
<button class="card-button" *ngFor="let env of product.env; let idx = index" 
[ngClass]="[idx == 0 ? 'selected' : 'notselected']" name="button">{{env.name}}</button>
```

Or you can color the button as below:

```
<button class="card-button" *ngFor="let env of product.env; let idx = index" 
[style.color]="{'green' : idx != 0, '#CC292B': idx == 0}" name="button">{{env.name}}</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`[style.color]`](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/) to `index=0`

```
[style.color]="{'#CC292B' : i == 0}"
```

See code:

```
<button class="card-button" *ngFor="let env of product.env;let i=index;" name="button" [style.color]="{'#CC292B' : i == 0}">{{env.name}}</button>
```

**BTW you can do only with css with [`:first-child`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp)**

```css
.card-button:first-child { 
    color: red;
}
```

```html
//like ngFor
<button class="card-button"  name="button">{{env.name}}</button>
<button class="card-button"  name="button">{{env.name}}</button>
<button class="card-button"  name="button">{{env.name}}</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the button style dynamically on user click use this:

In your component add this method:

```
public isselected=0;
buttonClick(index){
    this.isselected=index;
}
```

In HTML add the below code:

```
   <div *ngFor="let env of carsList; let i =index">
        <button (click)="buttonClick(i)" class="card-button" name="button" [ngClass]="[i == isselected ? 'button-active' : 'button-standard']" >{{env}}</button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[ngClass]` to add a class to the button that should get the focus automatically after the view is initialized.

```
<button 
    class="card-button" 
    *ngFor="let env of product.env; let i = index" 
    [ngClass]="[i == 0 ? 'autoFocusMe' : '']" 
    name="button">
    {{env.name}}
</button>
```

Then add method `ngAfterViewInit()` to your component.ts file to set the focus to that button

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    (<HTMLButtonElement>document.getElementsByClassName("autoFocusMe")[0]).focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created working example .Please check

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rk93xt